# Implied Volatility of cross currency pairs

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, currency

Been looking for this...

Is there any way we can infer directly, say GBP-JPY's 1-year volatility from GBP-USD's and USD-JPY's?

Many thanks.

Comment: In a Black/Scholes model - yes, given the correlation between GBP/USD and USD/JPY. See e.g. the first example in Uwe Wystup's paper "How the Greeks would have hedged correlation risk of foreign exchange options" which uses exactly those currency pairs.

Comment: See also this question https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/68822/triangular-arbitrage-in-fx-volatility/68826#68826

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your question is answered here:
[How should I convert FX Volatility Surface from one base currency to another?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/40527/how-should-i-convert-fx-volatility-surface-from-one-base-currency-to-another)

As they summarise, you need to make correlation assumptions. For an intuitive explanation of why this is the case, there's a nice framework for understanding the connection between volatilities and correlations in cross rates which you can find explained here:
https://quantdare.com/volatilities-and-correlations-of-cross-rates-a-geometrical-understanding/