# Triangular Arbitrage In FX Volatility

Tags: volatility, fx, arbitrage, limits-to-arbitrage

If I know the price of $GBPUSD$ and $EURUSD$, I can retrive the $EURGBP$ price simple by $EURGBP = \frac{GBPUSD}{EURUSD}$.

Is there something equivalent to FX Volatility? Knowing the $\sigma_{GBPUSD}$, $\sigma_{EURUSD}$ and myabe $\rho[GBPUSD,EURUSD]$, is there a direct relationship or bounds to the value of $\sigma_{EURGBP}$?

I tried to think in terms of generic numeraie, like $USDX$ and $GBPX$, and take expectaions of the ratios, but I found no solution.

Any idea or clue would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in the book "FX Derivatives Trader School" (and in other places, too, e.g. "The shape of things in a currency trio", a paper by Walter and Lopez, CS and FRB SF [link](https://www.frbsf.org/economic-research/files/wpjl99-04a.pdf)).

Comment: @noob2 - thanks for adding the link!

Comment: Thanks. It's simple a the volatility of a 'portfolio' invested 100% in both pairs. I should've seen that coming!